# firefox addon sdk - how to retrieve "currentTime" from youtube player on youtube.com?

Tags: firefox, youtube, youtube-api, firefox-addon, youtube-javascript-api

I am developing a firefox addon with SDK. What I want to do:

- If user is on a video of youtube the firefox addon knows the current position of youtube player (getCurrentTime())

I developed it with tabs

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
```

and when tab is ready, I added contentscripfiles to it with:

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.11.1.min.js"), data.url("myscript.js")]
});
```

In the script "myscript.js" I want to access to the youtube player on the youtube site.
I tried this:

```
var playerelement=document.getElementById("movie_player");
```

I got the "<embed>" DOM Element from it (with ID "movie_player"). But when I want to access to it with method "getCurrentTime()" there appears the following error:

```
Message: TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getCurrentTime is not a function
```

How can I access to the youtube player properly to get this stuff done?

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

`var playerelement=document.getElementById("movie_player");`

to

`var playerelement=document.getElementById('movie_player').wrappedJSObject;`

Now `getCurrentTime` will be accessible.